# Classification tree with less leafs than expected

Tags: r, tree, classification

My tree diagram only shows the two leafs: "DIFF" and "REG" and completely ignores the other values of the response variable. Why is the tree ignoring the other 6 values?. Does it have to do with the fact that they only represent a small percentage of the total values in my response variable?. Table below shows frequency count by value in response variable

```
35785   ED      1%
38060   NONE    1%
45880   INC     1%
49787   UT      1%
53108   OR      1%
165945  ET      4%
1728019 DIFF    43%
1894532 REG     47%
```

Comment: change your sampling to increase the proportion of other response variables. Also, without knowing something about the distribution of your predictors about your predictors - it is difficult to make any inference. You would be better off posting this question to CrossValidated since there is no programming example here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it is down to the unbalanced classes you refer to. Skewed data causes problems for machine learning algorithms. For example, clients of mine once naively built a fraud detection system using machine learning and were impressed when testing reported 97% accuracy with no tuning at all.

Turning out the prediction rule was "There's never any fraud". Fraud was so rare that that "rule set" resulted in 97% accuracy.

I assume something similar in your case---although without the details, I tend to sit on the fence.

There are [ways to address the issue](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/).

Comment: Thank you for your help dommer.